# Decrease the size of Twitter Feed

Tags: html, css, node.js, vue.js

I have been trying to decrease the size of my Twitter feed in order to make it look nice and place other components on the same page for my Vue.js page. How do I half the size of the feed and place it in a border? Thank you.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return { //returning data
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let twitterScript = document.createElement('script')
    twitterScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js')
    document.head.appendChild(twitterScript)
  }
}
```

```html
<template>    
      <div class="flex-box mt-3">
        <a class="twitter-timeline" 
           data-chrome="nofooter noheader noborders tranparent" 
           href="https://twitter.com/RyanMurph17/lists/manchester-united"></a>
      </div>    
</template>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I doubt you can mess with the formatting of it. Most social network widgets of this sort take steps to avoid you messing with their look/feel. If you want control, you'll probably need to directly work with the Twitter API.

Comment: Since you are using a Twitter Widget, the best bet is to check their documentation (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/overview) - scroll down to the section called: "Limiting the number of Tweets displayed"

Answer (score 1):

According to [their docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/overview), you need to include a limit to the number of Tweets displayed.  For example, to display only three Tweets, you indicate it like so:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"
  href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev"
  data-tweet-limit="3"><!-- adjust this number to your liking -->

    Tweets by @TwitterDev
</a>
```